# Javascript função quando clicar em qualquer class="xpto"

Tags: javascript, classes, click

Tenho um calendário onde todos os dias são:

```
<a class="dia" href="#">(Número do dia, ex: 1, 2, 3, etc)</a>
```

Aí preciso que sempre que a class "dia" for clicada ela chame uma função, por exemplo a função teste().

Fiz esse abaixo, mas o problema é que só consigo escolher 1 class, quero que funcione com qualquer uma:

```
<a class="dia" href="#">1</a>
<a class="dia" href="#">2</a>

<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("dia")[0].onclick = function() {teste()};
function teste() {
    alert("Deu Certo!");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Para selecionar todos os `elementos` de uma determinada classe, você pode usar a função `querySelectorAll()` que retornara um `array` com todos os `elementos` `<a>` que possuirem a condição informada, por exemplo:

```
var dias = document.querySelectorAll('.dia'); 
// Seleciona tudo que tiver a classe dia
```

Agora com os elementos capturados você precisará adicionar o evento `click` em cada um, para isso você pode utilizar a função `forEach()` para passar por cada elemento dentro da variavel `dias` e adicionar o `eventListener` de `click`:

```
function handleClick (event) {
    console.log('clicked');
}

dias.forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {once: false});
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas não completamente no calendario que estou usando, por algum motivo no calendario ele só funciona o primeiro clique, depois não funciona mais.

Comment: Incrementei a resposta veja se funciona.

Answer (score 4):

Neste momento está so a fazer para o primeiro link, o `[0]`. Pode estender a sua logica para aplicar a todos os elementos utilizando um `for`:

```js
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("dia");

for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length ; ++i){
  elementos[i].onclick = function() {teste()};
}

function teste() {
    alert("Deu Certo!");
}
```

```html
<a class="dia" href="#">1</a>
<a class="dia" href="#">2</a>
```

Ou utilizando uma das novas sintaxes de javascript o `for of`:

```js
for (let elemento of document.getElementsByClassName("dia")){
  elemento.onclick = function() {teste()};
}

function teste() {
    alert("Deu Certo!");
}
```

```html
<a class="dia" href="#">1</a>
<a class="dia" href="#">2</a>
```

Comment: Não sei porque, mas como nos outros quando testo só o código funciona normal, mas quando coloco no código do calendario, só funciona a 1ª vez

Comment: @LeandroTeraoka aconselho então a colocar o calendário que está a ser utilizado, ou partilhar um pouco mais de código para que nós possamos ajudar mais

Comment: O problema é que não me permitem divulgar nada do site :/
testei copiando só o código do calendário em um novo arquivo só com o html do calendario e o script e deu certo.

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer [como o Rafael sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219919/129) ou adicionar um ausculador global, que funciona como delegador para elementos ainda não criados quando a página carregou. Seria assim:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('minhaClasse')) return;
    // aqui podes correr o código ou chamar funções pois a classe foi clicada
});
```

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('minhaClasse')) return;
  // aqui podes correr o código ou chamar funções pois a classe foi clicada
  console.log('clicado!');
});
```

```html
<button>Normal</button>
<button class="minhaClasse">Com classe</button>
```

Comment: Não sei porque, mas como nos outros quando testo só o código funciona normal, mas quando coloco no código do calendario, só funciona a 1ª vez

Comment: @LeandroTeraoka podes criar um exemplo? assim posso ver e dizer o que não está a funcionar