# Qual a diferença entre "querySelector" e o "querySelectorAll"?

Tags: javascript

Preciso de uma ajuda para entender como funciona o `querySelector` e o `querySelectorAll`, estou acostuma a usar os seletores do jquery com  o `$()`, mas, quando eu uso o `querySelector` ele me retorna apenas o primeiro elemento e se eu usar o `querySelectorAll` eu não consigo adicionar eventos, então como eu faço para ter o mesmo efeito que um seletor do jquery usando javascript puro?

Comment: depois de utilizar document.querySelectorAll(selectors), Acho que pra adicionar evento com essas elementos deve adicionar addEventListener(), em um for...

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Javascript função quando clicar em qualquer class=“xpto”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219914/javascript-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-quando-clicar-em-qualquer-class-xpto) e/ou [Como adicionar um evento a todos elementos com a mesma classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/407962/como-adicionar-um-evento-a-todos-elementos-com-a-mesma-classe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll` são diferentes. O `querySelector` retorna o primeiro elemento dentro do documento e `querySelectorAll` retorna uma lista de elementos presentes no documento.

A forma para adicionar eventos usando javascript puro é usando o `addEventListener`. O `addEventListiner` deve receber dois parâmetros, primeiro o tipo do evento e segundo a ação que deve executar quando ocorrer aquele evento.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Olá")
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

No Exemplo acima, selecionamos um botão, quando hover um `click`(que o evento que esperamos), vamos executar uma função que inicia um `alert`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Agora com QuerySelectorAll");
  });
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<button>Click</button>
```

Para você aplicar o `addEventListener` em uma lista de elementos você deve interar esta lista, podendo faz isto com um `foreach`.

Comment: Mas e se eu usar o `querySelectorAll` para aplicar o `addEventListner` em todos os elementos igual no jquery ?