# querySelector e querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

estou sem saber como resolver um ponto de um exercício.

Tenho uma função JS que expande um texto dentro de uma div. Na primeira div ele funciona normalmente, mas na seguinte não ocorre nada.

como faço para que funcione em todas as divs.
Gostaria de entender o que não estou vendo pra que isso funcione. A ideia é que as duas divs tenham o mesmo nome class

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .conteudo h2 span{
            font-size: 13px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .conteudo p{
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 10px;
            transition: 1s;
        }

        .mostrar{
            height: 200px !important;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <h2>Título do conteúdo <span>ver mais</span></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
            elit. Pellentesque ac ligula vel sapien pellentesque 
            bibendum. Suspendisse posuere augue turpis, eget 
            luctus mauris molestie vel. Sed accumsan ex nibh, 
            vitae faucibus tortor luctus vitae. Sed aliquet, 
            diam sit amet porttitor suscipit, nisi velit venenatis 
            velit, eu accumsan orci ipsum commodo felis. In lectus 
            ipsum, fermentum non egestas sit amet, pellentesque 
            nec lacus. Donec erat lectus, gravida nec sagittis at, 
            sollicitudin vel turpis. Cras in pulvinar est.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="conteudo">
        <h2>Título do conteúdo <span>ver mais</span></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
            elit. Pellentesque ac ligula vel sapien pellentesque 
            bibendum. Suspendisse posuere augue turpis, eget 
            luctus mauris molestie vel. Sed accumsan ex nibh, 
            vitae faucibus tortor luctus vitae. Sed aliquet, 
            diam sit amet porttitor suscipit, nisi velit venenatis 
            velit, eu accumsan orci ipsum commodo felis. In lectus 
            ipsum, fermentum non egestas sit amet, pellentesque 
            nec lacus. Donec erat lectus, gravida nec sagittis at, 
            sollicitudin vel turpis. Cras in pulvinar est.</p>
    </div>

    <script>

        var span = document.querySelector('.conteudo span');

         span.addEventListener('click', function(){
             alert('funcionou');

            var conteudo = document.querySelector('.conteudo p');

            if(conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')){
                span.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
                conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
            }else{
                span.innerHTML = 'Ver menos!';
                conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');
            }
            
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ignorem o alert dentro da função

Comment: quando usei o querySelectorAll para de funcionar

Comment: @hkotsubo entendi que o querySelectorAll precisa iterar por meio de um loop para saber qual div está sendo clicada. No entanto trazer para essa questão aqui não está sendo simples pra mim.

Comment: Se entendi direito, acho que é isso que vc quer fazer: https://jsfiddle.net/nd8jvto6/

Comment: @hkotsubo perfeito! Vou estudar o teu código que ai tem coisa além do meu conhecimento! Agradecido demais!

Comment: @hkotsubo coloca como uma resposta pra eu fechar o tópico e votar na tua resposta. Coloca somente o código js

Comment: Respondi, mas mudei um pouco o código, acho que ficou um pouco melhor do que o jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426718/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-queryselector-e-o-queryselectorall), `querySelectorAll` [retorna uma lista de elementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Return_value), então você deve percorrer esta lista para adicionar os eventos em cada elemento. Já `querySelector` [retorna apenas o primeiro elemento que for encontrado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value).

Só que aí muda um pouco a forma como você faz. Dentro do `addEventListener` você busca pelo parágrafo que está na mesma `div` do `span` clicado, então não adianta usar `querySelector` lá dentro. Ou seja, esta linha:

```js
var conteudo = document.querySelector('.conteudo p');
```

Retorna sempre o `p` que está na primeira `div`. Então você tem que mudar um pouco a forma como faz a busca.

Eu sugiro fazer o seguinte:

- busque por todas as `div`'s que têm a classe `conteudo`
- adicione o evento de clique no `span` que está dentro da `div`
- mude a classe do `p` que está dentro da `div`

Ficaria assim:

```js
// procura as div's que têm a classe "conteudo"
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.conteudo');

// para cada div
divs.forEach(div => {
    // procura o span que está na div e adiciona o evento de clique
    var span = div.querySelector('span');
    span.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // procura o p que está dentro da div
        var conteudo = div.querySelector('p');
        if (conteudo.classList.contains('mostrar')) {
            span.innerHTML = 'Ver mais!';
            conteudo.classList.remove('mostrar');
        } else {
            span.innerHTML = 'Ver menos!';
            conteudo.classList.add('mostrar');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.conteudo h2 span{
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.conteudo p{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.mostrar{
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
    <h2>Título do conteúdo <span>ver mais</span></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        elit. Pellentesque ac ligula vel sapien pellentesque 
        bibendum. Suspendisse posuere augue turpis, eget 
        luctus mauris molestie vel. Sed accumsan ex nibh, 
        vitae faucibus tortor luctus vitae. Sed aliquet, 
        diam sit amet porttitor suscipit, nisi velit venenatis 
        velit, eu accumsan orci ipsum commodo felis. In lectus 
        ipsum, fermentum non egestas sit amet, pellentesque 
        nec lacus. Donec erat lectus, gravida nec sagittis at, 
        sollicitudin vel turpis. Cras in pulvinar est.</p>
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
    <h2>Título do conteúdo 2 <span>ver mais</span></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        elit. Pellentesque ac ligula vel sapien pellentesque 
        bibendum. Suspendisse posuere augue turpis, eget 
        luctus mauris molestie vel. Sed accumsan ex nibh, 
        vitae faucibus tortor luctus vitae. Sed aliquet, 
        diam sit amet porttitor suscipit, nisi velit venenatis 
        velit, eu accumsan orci ipsum commodo felis. In lectus 
        ipsum, fermentum non egestas sit amet, pellentesque 
        nec lacus. Donec erat lectus, gravida nec sagittis at, 
        sollicitudin vel turpis. Cras in pulvinar est.</p>
</div>
```

Repare que em vez de fazer a busca a partir do `document`, eu fiz:

```js
var span = div.querySelector('span');
```

Assim, ele busca somente pelo `span` que está dentro do elemento apontado por `div` (em vez de buscar em todo o documento). Isso garante que vou adicionar o evento de clique no elemento que está dentro daquela `div`. O mesmo vale para a busca pelo `p`, que é feita a partir da `div`, assim eu garanto que vou mudar a classe do elemento correto.

Comment: eu estou impressionado como você foi didático nessa resposta! Se você não for um professor tem tudo pra ser! Estou agora tentando mudar o motivo pra de fato absorver isso do querySelector e estou conseguindo ter resultados. Grato demais @hkotsubo